# Kann man »bzw.« nutzen, um das gleiche Verb in verschiedenen Zeiten anzudeuten?

Tags: grammar

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob der folgende Satz richtig ist:

> Herr Müller bzw. Herr Mustermann wohnt bzw. hat gewohnt hier.

Was ich sagen will ist, dass die erste Person *jetzt hier wohnt* und die zweite, *hier in die Vergangenheit wohnte*. Trotz des Magels an Schönheit, finde ich ökonomisch, beide Behauptungen in einem Satz sammeln zu können. Gleichzeitig lernt man, wie *beziehungsweise* angewendet wird, wenn es *respectively* bedeutet.

Comment: Ich würde (wenn überhaupt) schreiben: »Herr Müller und Herr Mustermann wohnen bzw. wohnten hier.« oder »Herr Müller und Herr Mustermann wohnen hier bzw. haben hier gewohnt.«

Comment: `Herr Müller wohnt und Herr Mustermann wohnte hier.` Hat gewohnt hier keinesfalls, allenfalls hat hier gewohnt. Daher wird es aber nichts mit dem geschmeidigen Einschub. Was "bzw." ausdrücken soll erschließt sich mir nicht.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you gave doesn't work on a grammatical level and the reason is the word **hier**.

In part 1, it is the last word of the clause, while in part 2 it stands between *hat* and *gewohnt*. That has the effect that in the first clause it sounds quite predicative - that is to say, it sounds like it is part of the verbal phrase with the action being *hier wohnen*. In the second clause it is more just a local information because the final position is occupied by *gewohnt*, thus the predicate is more *gewohnt haben*. The *hier* does not have the same weight and is not placed at the same rhythmical position. Thus, you can't skip it.

> Herr X bzw. Herr Z. wohnt hier bzw. hat hier gewohnt.

If we use the preterite, the *hier* is at the end in both sentences and can thus be skipped once.

> ... wohnt bzw. wohnte hier.

It also works if you make that whole thing a minor sentence.

> Ich wusste nicht, dass Herr X bzw. Herr Z. nicht hier wohnt bzw. gewohnt hat.

Also here, the *hier* carries the same "weight".

Now, in general I would say that this sentence is maybe not wrong but definitely not very good. It is hard to tell what bzw. refers to what and I can only understand the sentence with a little analyzing. It doesn't come automatically. So if you want to separate 2 entities and to respective actions, I would recommend not using a double bzw. because it doesn't "span". The first impression is always that the second entity (Herr Z) does both the actions.

Answer (score 4):

Only an addition to Emanuel's answer.

This double `bzw.` is really bad style. It has a highly logical structure and can be analyzed just as easily as other grammatical structures. But it just sounds and reads horrible, because it doesn't suit the common usage.

Alternatives:

> Herr Müller und Herr Mustermann wohnen bzw. wohnten hier.
>
> Herr Müller und Herr Mustermann wohnen hier bzw. haben hier gewohnt.
>
> Herr Müller wohnt und Herr Mustermann wohnte hier.

Just for the real nerds here a mathematical reasoning for this:

The difference betwenn your suggestion and the actual usage is the same as the difference between the domain of a function and its arguments or the range of the function and its values.

Your suggestion uses arguments and function values which are declared as having the same index in two lists each separated by `bzw.`.

The common usage uses the domain, which is given as a list separated by `und` and furtheron dealt with as an entity (recognizable by the plural form of the verb), and the function values in a list separated by `bzw.`.

Comment: Tja, eigentlich habe ich an Mathe gedacht, als ich die Frage gestellt habe; allerdingst in andere Richtung. Als triviales Muster gilt der Satz »Wenn $\epsilon=+1$ bzw. $\epsilon=-1$, gleicht  $e^x+\epsilon e^{-x}$ $2\cosh x$ bzw. $2\sinh x$« (to be read as LaTeX), weil man in Englischen immer so zusammenfasst.

Comment: Ja, wird im Deutschen aber eben nicht so gemacht. Aber wenn du sowieso Mathematik schreibst, dann kannst du doch auch mathematisches bzw. geometrisches Markup verwenden. Also zum Beispiel: „Wenn \begin{tabular}{c}\(\epsilon=+1\)\\\(\epsilon=-1\)\end{tabular}, dann gleicht \(e^x+\epsilon e^{-x}\) \begin{tabular}{c}\(2\cosh x\)\\\(2\sinh x\)\end{tabular}.“ oder nimm eine `cases` Umgebung.